# Differences between $\{ \rho_n \}$ and $ \rho_n $, mollifier

Tags: real-analysis, notation, lp-spaces

What is the difference between the two notations about mollifiers $\{ \rho_n \}$ and  $ \rho_n $?
I'm a little bit confused, I want to study convergence and limitations in $L^2(R^3)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your reference is using this notation, it is using $\{ \rho_n \}$ to refer to the whole sequence and $\rho_n$ to refer to the $n$th element of the sequence.